# How can I solve this css issue?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to fix this problem for probably over a week now and I don't understand it.

The problem is simple to describe I guess..
Here's my website [website](http://vlogbog.pe.hu/)

As you can see everything looks good but then if you click on a torrent everything starts looking weird (the width of the page)

This page for example. [example](http://vlogbog.pe.hu/torrent/info/3)

How can I fix this? Please help me..

Screenshots: gyazo.com/d4576b4e4e4f5407c903bc0e4b3ba969
             gyazo.com/bf927dfdba38c40efd1ee1e2723b6567

Thank you

Comment: fix your html first, there are a lot mistakes just at the beginning, `meta` tags before `doctype`

Comment: what should I fix, what html, what page? @dippas

Answer (score 0):

Tested and this seems to work within the inspect element portion.

Navigate to

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url(../images/wallpaper_dark.jpg);
    color: #eaeaea;
    font-family: Calibri, Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 915px;
}
```

and then replace the bottom part `width: 915px;` with `max-width: 915px;` with a `width: 100%;`.

[image]

For the issue with the image at the top not going full scale I guess you could do something like this.

```
background-image: url(/images/banner.jpg);
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

which will return something that looks like this.

[image]

This is off topic but I recommend moving the META tags you have

[image]

Below the `<html lang="sv_SE">` portion on your site so it would look something like.

```
<html lang="sv_SE">
<head style="height: 100%">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

instead of how you currently have it.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="sv_SE">
<head style="height: 100%">
```

Comment: Hello there! I've now replaced what you said but it's not working. Please check. For the image; it's already full-size it's just the page that needs to have same width like on index (first page) Best Regards

Comment: Hello there! I've now replaced what you said but it's not working. Please check. For the image; it's already full-size it's just the page that needs to have same width like on index (first page) Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this div paddingtop_20 (it's a div nested quite deep inside div#myElement) I would post screenshots but I don't have enough reputation.

The issue is that the text inside does not have white spaces to break the text so that it can go into the next line. You can change the css on paddingtop_20 to have a max-width:[enter some max-width] and set overflow:scroll. Otherwise, find a way to break the text inside.

Comment: Sorry. That's does not work. Thanks for helping anyways : )

Comment: It's the body that changes when I click to that other page. I don't want the width to change.

Comment: The body changes because the content inside changes. If you inspect the element and delete the div paddingtop_20 you'll see that it goes back to normal. Did you test with max-width as something small like 100px? I'm very certain it's that div.

Comment: The max-width isn't to change the width. It's to restrict the text from stretching the inner div. When the inner div stretches everything outside it (the table and the outer divs) also stretch.

Comment: But I tested to change the css on paddingtop_20 to have a max-width: [enter some max-width] and I also set a overflow:scroll but it did not work. Yes I tried now to set the max-width to 100px but it did not work either.

Comment: Did you replace [enter some max-width] with a max-width? (Say, 100px). Yes, if you delete it temporarily you will see that it fixes the page.

Comment: Please check the site. I've deleted paddingtop_20 without results.

Comment: I can still see it. If you click the first torrent (The Revenant) it's the part that has this text: Beskrivning
___________________________________________________________________________________rnrn The Revenant (2015)rn rn___________________________________________________________________________________rnrnrnIMDB.........................: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663202/rnGENRE........................: Adventure, Drama, Thriller rnFORMAT.......................: MKVrnCODEC........................: X264, 1522 kb/srnAUDIO........................: AC3 5 .. etc

Comment: Please check again

Comment: Please check again. I've updated now and there is no paddingtop_20 anymore and the problem is still there

Comment: Hmm I just checked and it looks fixed in my browser. I am using Chrome.